# VSIX: Command menu item visibility depend on option value

Tags: c#, menuitem, vsix

I have just completed a basic VSIX package which provides only one command. The command takes the selection from a C# file and does some refactoring, the details of which are uninteresting for this question.

The menu place where I let the command item appear is, unsurprisingly, the context menu of the code editor.

As the kind of refactoring provided is only seldom needed, I would prefer to be able to show this menu item entry only when the user makes an appropriate selection in the OptionDialog of the package. Although currently no Option Page is included, I think, I understand its mechanics well enough to provide a simple "Display: True/False" alternative option.

But what I do not understand very well, even after some searching, what would be the easiest/most canonical/most modern way to implement the visibility part - I understand this is called "dynamic visibility". The most comprehensive tutorial example for this seems to be

[Making Visual Studio extension command visibility optional](https://route2roslyn.netlify.app/making-visual-studio-extension-command-visibility-optional/)

Unfortunately this requires going to quite baroque complications, even reading and writing into the registry explicitly. The problem seems to be mainly that the simpler part of setting the visibility of the menu item is to do this, when the package is loaded. So one can make one's life simpler by autoloading the package as early as possible - but this is declared unwishable by many tutorials.

So my question is: *What would be the most concise and modern way to accomplish dynamic visibility of a command menu item depending on an option page entry?*

(Maybe try to answer in the spirit of the [VSIX Cookbook](https://www.vsixcookbook.com/), that seems to advertise the most modern way of VSIX development, using the "Community Extensibility Extensions" where no DTE objects appear and everything is now done via VS objects and the method annotations seem to be more concise too).